# PowerShell Displaying blank lines while trying to display registry values

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get list of installed program on any system. wmi Products does not display some programs so I am trying to use Power shell to get list of installed software. Following code appears to display many lines but they all all blank. Am I missing something?

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\*" | Select-object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: When I run your first command, none of your selected fields `DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate` are part of the output.   `Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\*" | ft -property IsInstalled, Locale, Version` shows some fields though. YMMV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistaking the registry key path. To list installed software, perhaps this will do a better job:

```
$regKeys = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
foreach ($key in $regKeys) {
    Write-Host $key -ForegroundColor Yellow

    Get-ItemProperty $key | 
        Where-Object { $_.DisplayName } |
        Sort-Object -Property DisplayName, InstallDate |
        Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
```